# Write Raw Binary to file System Phonegap / Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, binary, html5-filesystem

I am using a API in my application that returns an image in binary. I am trying to write this to a file using cordova fileWriter.

Assuming `var data` contains the binary returned. I am successfully able to write this to the fileSystem(`writer.write(data);`) . However the image is corrupt and does not open.

Do i need to do something to the data received before writing it? Perhaps convert it to something? . I am unfamiliar with manipulating Binary Data. Would appreciate any help